Usage of "Sich-Einfügen"

In meiner Kultur ist Geld zwar auch ein relevanter Aspekt, aber noch wichtiger ist für uns die Harmonie und das Sich-Einfügen in die gesellschaftliche Ordnung.

Could someone explain to me how to translate "Sich-Einfügen" in the above sentence? What type of grammatical object is it supposed to be?

It's a nominalization of the verb phrase sich einfügen — to integrate.

Man muss auch selbst etwas tun, um sich in eine Gruppe einzufügen.


could you give me more details? this is the first time I've seen such a nominalization

Such nominalizations with hyphens are clunky. Don't use them yourself. If the verb phrase has a non-verbal component as e.g. sich, it's better to stick to a verbal phrasing.

Wdym by "verbal phrasing"? and wdym by non-verbal component? In the trivial interpretation I make, that is the case with every sentence, since everything except the vebr is non verbal

E.g. … aber noch wichtiger ist für uns die Harmonie und, sich in die gesellschaftliche Ordnung einzufügen. That's much better.

Or … aber noch wichtiger ist für uns die Harmonie und, dass man sich in die gesellschaftliche Ordnung einfügt.
